# Audio Files accurate seek to

Tags: java, android, mp3

Which Audio format should I use to get the best accurate seek to? (play the song from an offset)
I whant this to be accurate on the millisecond.

is that Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I can say that the format of the audio file matters. I had this problem with long mp3 file. As the mp3 files aren't designed for such accurate seeking you can check this answer for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747530/348589)

In my case the bitrate of the mp3 file was low, It was 96Kps. and the VBR data wasn't correct which caused the mp3 file to seek wrongly on android.

My intent was to make android and IOS app that seeks accurately through this file but I failed to find the correct format that is suitable for both.

**For the IOS,** I used [MP3 Diags](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3diags/) and applied custom transformations to remove and rebuild the VBR

**For Android,** I converted the file to m4a format and it worked perfectly. I used [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and installed the [FFmpeg package](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/faq_installing_the_ffmpeg_import_export_library.html) to be able to export to m4a format.

This is [the file sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sZI8nSqBoFBY9Pr7ryqyyAOfZ6-5aMcC) that contains the problem I mentioned

Answer (score -2):

The format doesn't matter, as long as it's compatible with Android's [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class. It has a [seekTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29) method that is accrate to the millisecond.

Comment: yes i know but i checked it and it's not realy accrate. plus i can see it changes from file to file, so i belive the format affects the accrate

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- it's accurate down to the millisecond. So if you're not getting it to play accurately enough, then your audio file needs to be encoded wit a higher bitrate. It's also possible that it's a phone limitation -- no matter how accureately you seek in the MediaPlayer, it might take your phone some time to actually start playing back the audio (the slowe the phone, the less accurate it might be)

Comment: the bitrate is the only parameter that can effect the accurately?

Comment: Actually no, you also want to increase the sampling rate. And now that I've though about this a bit more, you probably should test your audio file on the PC -- it's possiblen that you're losing audio data while encoding or compressing the file. But if the file can be seeked precisely on your PC, then it should work the same wayin Android