# Precise seek in MP3 files on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp3, exoplayer

I'm building an app where it's important to have accurate seeking in MP3 files.

Currently, I'm using ExoPlayer in the following manner:

```
public void playPeriod(long startPositionMs, long endPositionMs) {

    MediaSource mediaSource = new ClippingMediaSource(
            new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(mDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mFileUri),
            startPositionMs * 1000,
            endPositionMs * 1000
    );

    mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

}
```

In some cases, this approach results in offsets of 1-3 seconds relative to the expected playback times.

[I found this issue on ExoPlayer's github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4676). Looks like this is an intrinsic limitation of ExoPlayer with Mp3 format and it won't be fixed.

[I also found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401733/android-mediaextractor-seek-accuracy-with-mp3-audio-files) which seems to suggest that the same issue exists in Android's native MadiaPlayer and MediaExtractor.

Is there a way to perform accurate seek in local (e.g. on-device) Mp3 files on Android? I'm more than willing to take any hack or workaround.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MP3 files are not inherently seekable.  They don't contain any timestamps.  It's just a series of MPEG frames, one after the other.  That makes this tricky.  There are two methods for seeking an MP3, each with some tradeoffs.

The most common (and fastest) method is to read the bitrate from the first frame header (or, maybe the average bitrate from the first few frame headers), perhaps 128k.  Then, take the byte length of the entire file, divide it by this bitrate to estimate the time length of the file.  Then, let the user seek into the file.  If they seek `1:00` into a `2:00` file, divide the byte size of the file to the 50% mark and "needle drop" into the stream.  Read the file until a sync word for the next frame header comes by, and then begin decoding.

As you can imagine, this method isn't accurate.  At best, you're going to be within a half frame of the target on-average.  With frame sizes being 576 samples, this is pretty accurate.  However, there are problems with calculating the needle drop point in the first place.  The most common issue is that ID3 tags and such add size to the file, throwing off the size calculations.  A more severe issue is a variable bitrate (VBR) file.  If you have music encoded with VBR, and the beginning of the track is silent-ish or otherwise easy to encode, the beginning might be 32 kbps whereas one second in might be 320 kbps.  A 10x error in calculating the time length of the file!

The second method is to decode the whole file to raw PCM samples.  This means you can guarantee sample-accurate seeking, but you *must* decode at least up to the seek point.  If you want a proper time length for the full track, you *must* decode the whole file.  Some 20 years ago, this was painfully slow.  Seeking into a track would take almost as long as listening to the track to the point you were seeking to!  These days, for short files, you can probably decode them so fast that it doesn't matter so much.

TL;DR; If you must have sample-accurate seeking, decode the files first before putting them in your player, but understand the performance penalty first before deciding this tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks for a very informative reply. I wouldn't mind to explore your suggestion about decoding the file first, but I don't know what you mean by that. Do you happen to know of a resource where I could read about this topic? Otherwise, can you suggest several search terms for me to google to get a general idea of what you suggest?

Comment: @Vasiliy I'm no Android developer, but I think you would use MediaExtractor (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor) to demux the file (perhaps not even necessary for MP3!), and MediaCodec (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) to actually decode it.  Some Googling led to this code for AAC:  https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample/blob/master/src/net/thdev/mediacodecexample/decoder/AudioDecoderThread.java  It should be similar to do the same for MP3.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help. This should get me started. I'll accept the answer later if there will be nothing more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. I had an issue and your answer help me to understand the problem and find a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57916886/348589

Comment: @shadysherif No problem!  Glad you found this helpful.

Comment: But don't we know that there are exactly 1152 samples in a typical dual channel frame? Can't we use this somehow to figure out an exact frame we got to start from? shouldn't there be some relation between sample and timing?

Comment: @jayarjo The issue isn't the frame count, it's the byte offset.  The number of bytes required to encode a frame can vary.

Comment: Now that I read about it some more, I think your answer is not entirely correct. For example VBR files have TOCs at the beginning that help in seeking.

Comment: @jayarjo Not all do.  This is a bit of a hack that was added on by some encoders later.  It isn't common to see in files in the wild, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

For those who might come across this issue in the future, I ended up simply converting mp3 to m4a. This was the simplest solution in my specific case.

Comment: It would be far better to go back to the original source rather that converting from MP3s.  MP3 and AAC are both lossy.  Converting between them results in additional quality loss.

Comment: @Brad Well, sometimes all you've got is mp3 files and you need to ensure accurate seek functionality. Even if it means quality loss...

Comment: You can put MP3 audio in an MP4 container just as you can with AAC, and get the benefit of timestamps in the container that way.  `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp4`

Comment: @Brad interesting. If that project will require any more maintenance, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tested that MP3 -> MP4 with emulated slow network. And indeed it works for browsers too, sometimes browsers try to seek MP3 file by range request, but they fail. However with MP4 it seemed to work way better at doing range requests.

Comment: I tested `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp4` in iOS Safari it does not open the file as audio player. However if you have m4a and rename it to mp4 it works.

Comment: @Brad, I was skeptical about changing container, but indeed it gives precise seeking on html5 even with 12 hour VBR mp3 files and solves my problems without getting into those other painful solutions.

Comment: @RolandasDundulis Glad to hear it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

Constant bitrate mp3s are better. The system i used was to record the sample offset location of each frame header in the mp3 into a list. Then to seek, I would seek to the closest frame header before the desired sample by using the values in the list and then read from that location to my desired sample. This works fairly well but not perfect as the rendered wave form is decoded from the reference frame not the values if you decoded from start of file. If accuracy is reqired use libmpg123 it appears to be almost sample accurate. Note check licencing if for commercial app.

Comment: So there's a relation between sample and the seek time after all. Could you please elaborate on this?