# Split mp3 into independently playable pieces that can be stitched back if required

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, mp3

I would like to stream an mp3. However decoding it on a sending party will eat up the bandwidth. Is it possible to retain compressed format and still be able to slice it into independently playable chunks? Then I could send them out one by one and queue up and/or stitch it back on a receiving party. From what I've heard mp3 specifically (not sure about other formats) should allow something like this by specification.

It is also highly probable that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about audio playback in general. Please advice.

Comment: Sounds like you just have a big continuous stream that you need to seek into, right?

Comment: Potentially receiver should be able to seek - yes, so basically request an arbitrary chunk from sender that corresponds to the requested time.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use HTTP ranged requests?  This is exactly what most browsers do already... they request portions of the file to be played, as needed by the user.

Comment: I'm going to stream it over raw TCP socket, but - yes it might boil down to something as simple as range requesting. However from what I read now - mp3 frames are not necessarily independent, some of them may need to be combined.

Comment: That's correct.  The bit reservoir can smatter data for one frame to others as a sort of VBR within a CBR stream.  However, the players take care of this for you and will figure out what they need to play back.  The one tricky thing is that MP3 files aren't inherently seekable.  (See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747530/362536)  Players get around this with a few hacks.  If you're making your own lower level player, you may need to implement those same hacks.  I'd also encourage you to look beyond MP3 if possible.  It's certainly not the best codec we have right now.

Comment: Which codec would you suggest?

Comment: Opus is the go-to codec these days, if the device compatibility is good enough for you.  It's supported by most things.  https://caniuse.com/#search=opus  It has the best audio quality and its encoder is royalty-free.  If you need broader compatibility, AAC is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the RTP specification for the mp3 streaming

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5219

the same concept of chunks and frame has been taken care in the specification.

you can use the mp3 encoded data from the mp3 file, pack them using the rtp specification and do unpack rtp and then combine/write them into mp3 file.

Comment: Do you know of any implementation of this protocol, preferably in JavaScript, but potentially can be C/C++ or Rust?

Comment: I am not aware of any RTP/RTSP javascript solution, you can have a look at C/C++ solution : http://www.live555.com/

Comment: check ffmpeg javascript wrapper : https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js/

Comment: I will mark you are answer as correct, since it the end it brought me to my own implementation. Thanks.